# Why can't I extend everyone's pocket in nowjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, nowjs-sockets, ecmascript-harmony

I'm trying to provide functions in everyone's `pocket` of nowjs. I'd like to do so by `_.extend`ing everyone's pocket, i.e. `everyone.now`. For some reason which I cannot understand, `_.extend` fails to properly provide the function at the client side.

This is my current code:

```
var _ = require("underscore"),
    everyone = require("nowjs").initialize(app);

everyone.now.foo = function() {};

_.extend(everyone.now, {
    bar: function() {}
});

console.log(everyone.now.foo); // [Function]
console.log(everyone.now.bar); // undefined
```

On both the server and client sides, I can do `now.foo()` just fine. On the other hand, `now.bar()` fails because `now.bar` is not defined. This is the case on both the client and server sides. I tried to check for existence at the server side, as shown above on the last line. However, this line logs `undefined`.

Underscore's `extend` function (obviously) does work on other objects so I guess it has something to do with the "magical namespace" that nowjs uses.

How come extending doesn't work with `everyone.now` and how can I get it to work?

---

**Edit 2:** I digged some more into proxies. It seems like setting a property on a proxy by passing a variable as its name does not work. I removed my first edit because this testcase is more narrowed down.

Why is this not working? Is this a bug? (Most of the times I ask this myself I know it isn't, but this is really making me clueless...)

```
var proxy = Proxy.create({
    get: function(pr, name) {
        console.log("get called");
        return null;
    },

    set: function(pr, name, value) {
        console.log("set called");
    }
});

var key = "foo";

proxy["foo"] = "bar";
proxy[ key ] = "bar";

proxy["foo"];
proxy[ key ];
```

Log result:

```
set called
get called
get called
```

Apparently, `proxy[ key ] = "bar";` does not cause `set` to be called on the proxy. Why is that?

Comment: Running that same thing on my system gets the expected result of two calls to each function. What version of node and node-proxy do you have?

Comment: @Logan F. Smyth: I'm running on node 0.6.5 which came out yesterday. I'm running node with the `--harmony_proxies` flag, so I don't need the third party library. It might be that V8's implementation contains bugs at the moment whereas node-proxy does not. I'll check that out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They [posted a blog entry](http://blog.nowjs.com/running-nowjs-natively-on-windows) on the NowJS website on how to use `node-proxy` on Windows, instead of the native V8 implementation using the `--harmony_proxies` flag.

It appeared that the V8 version that Node currently uses contains several bugs with regard to proxies, which were causing the weird behaviour as outlined in the question. `node-proxy`, however, is a module that enables proxies (the core of the "magical namespace" of NowJS) *without* those bugs. (The bugs are fixed in a newer version of V8 as well, but that would require a custom build of Node.)

I just couldn't figure out how to build `node-proxy` on Windows (it's a `.node` addon; not a pure JavaScript one). In the above blog post they distributed the compiled module, and everything now works like a charm.

To fix:

- Download [the compiled module](https://github.com/Flotype/now/zipball/windows)
- Extract the folder to the `node_modules` folder and rename it to `now`
- Don't run Node with the proxy flag

---

**Edit:** Node 0.7.0 uses V8 3.8.6 which also solves this issue. Just run with the `--harmony` flag and remove the reference to `node-proxy`.